# How to effectively save last 7 days statistics in SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to save statistics from past 7 days. But tomorrow I need to remove or replace data that was saving 8 days ago.
I was thinking about having a table with 8 columns (name + 7 days) and every night remove last one and create new but it sound bad.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: When you add new data, you add it though new records, not via rotating data in columns.

Comment: Why not simply store all statistics? Failing that, three columns (name, date, value), 7 rows, and update the oldest one